# How to convert slice of structs to slice of strings in go?

Tags: go, struct, slice

New go user here. 
I have a slice of this struct objects:

```
type TagRow struct {
    Tag1 string  
    Tag2 string  
    Tag3 string  
}
```

Which yeilds slices like:

```
[{a b c} {d e f} {g h}]
```

I'm wondering how can I convert the resulting slice to a slice of strings like:

```
["a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"]
```

I tried to iterate over like:

```
for _, row := range tagRows {
for _, t := range row {
    fmt.Println("tag is" , t)
}
```

}

But I get:

```
cannot range over row (type TagRow)
```

So appreciate your help.

Comment: You can try the [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#example_StructTag) library.

Comment: @kichik could not figure out how. Can you elaborate your answer please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your specific case I would just do it "manually":

```
rows := []TagRow{
    {"a", "b", "c"},
    {"d", "e", "f"},
    {"g", "h", "i"},
}

var s []string
for _, v := range rows {
    s = append(s, v.Tag1, v.Tag2, v.Tag3)
}
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
```

Output:

```
["a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"]
```

If you want it to dynamically walk through all fields, you may use the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package. A helper function which does that:

```
func GetFields(i interface{}) (res []string) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    for j := 0; j < v.NumField(); j++ {
        res = append(res, v.Field(j).String())
    }
    return
}
```

Using it:

```
var s2 []string
for _, v := range rows {
    s2 = append(s2, GetFields(v)...)
}
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s2)
```

Output is the same:

```
["a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"]
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0nS9tC6cGY).

See similar questions with more complex examples:

[Golang, sort struct fields in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913483/golang-sort-struct-fields-in-alphabetical-order)

[How to print struct with String() of fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142594/how-to-print-struct-with-string-of-fields)