# Dynamic struct member names like in javascript in golang

Tags: oop, object, go, struct, notation

I am writing a multi-lang website.
I read the language info from users cookies, and I have several translation modules such as `en.go` `gr.go` etc.
The modules are of type `map[string]string`.The problem here is in javascript I can do something like `lang[cookies.lang]["whatever message"].'But go does not support accessing struct members in this way. 
I could make switch case or`map[string]map[string]string` and map all possible languages, but this is much extra work.
So is there any way golang provides some way to access members like js brackets notation?
Not: There was a similar question on the stack, and somebody wrote to use "reflect" package, but I could not quite understand how it works and failed to reproduce by myself works and failed to reproduce by myself.

Comment: Here are some examples how to access fields of struct values based on their names using `reflect`: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30889373/1705598); [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39968350/1705598); [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913483/golang-sort-struct-fields-in-alphabetical-order/30915092#30915092); [four](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33142636/1705598).

Comment: what are the reasons for people to give minus points without a note? How silly question right ? the ones who voted minus are familiar with any kinda technology i guess

Comment: @nikoss I think it is because this reads very much like a "how can I write JavaScript in Go" question. You can't, they have different capabilities. All in all, I think a `map[string]map[string]string` is the right solution in Go and it should not require much more typing than using structs, dynamically find packages, or whatever else you were considering using reflection for.

Comment: @Vatine that was the question; how to use reflection. This has nothing to do with js it was just an example of how it's done in js

Answer (score 1):

One possible route would be to use a `map[string]map[string]string`.

You could then have a base package in which you declare your base translation variable and in your translation modules, you can use an `init` function to populate the relevant sub-map. It's essentially optional if you want to do this as separate packages or just separate files (doing it as packages means you have better compile-time control of what languages to include, doing it as files is probably less confusing).

If you go the packages root, I suggest the following structure:

```
translation/base          This is where you export from
translation/<language>    These are "import only" packages
```

Then, in translation/base:

```
package "base"
var Lang map[string]map[string]string
```

And in each language-specific package:

```
package "<language code>"

import "language/base"

var code = "<langcode>"

func init() {
  d := map[string]string{}
  d[<phrase1>] = "your translation here"
  d[<phrase2>] = "another translation here"
  // Do this for all the translations
  base.Lang[code] = d
}
```

Then you can use this from your main program:

```
package "..."

import (
   "language/base"
   _ "language/lang1" // We are only interested in side-effects
   _ "language/lang2" // Same here...
)
```

Not using separate packages is (almost) the same. You simply ensure that all the files are in the same package and you can skip the package prefix for the `Lang` variable.

A toy example [on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4ctb4BoBr0), with all the "fiddly" bits inlined.

Comment: Thats what i thought too. In the question i mentioned that but this is not the only case i need dynamic calls for thats why i upvoted but this is not exactly the answer i am looking for anyway this is the go way to do this stuff i think just it gets messy when you have a lot of stuff to call dynamically